# Limit SSH login by originating interface

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, filtering

I want to allow anybody in the  `192.168.1.0-192.168.1.255` range to be able to log in with a password or a SSH key, but people outside that range to only be able to log in with a SSH key.

Can this be accomplished without more than one sshd?

I'm on Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is untested, but setting up something like this at the very end of `sshd_config` should work:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes

Match Address 192.168.1.0/24
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Basically you're globally allowing public key auth, globally disallowing password auth, and then specifically *re*-allowing password authentication for anyone in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

Edit:
You probably already have the first three lines elsewhere in your config.  If you do, they do not need to be added again.  However the "Match" block *must* be at the end of the file.

Also, the `RSAAuthentication` keyword is specific to SSH v1, which you don't allow, right?

Comment: hey, your answer worked great, thanks. I just had to add "Address" between "Match" and the IP address. Can you edit it to add that to the directive?

Comment: Good catch.  Done.

Comment: this "Match Address" block is superb. I just used it to enable root logins on 192.168.1.0!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think so. You can use the AllowUser and MatchUser directives in the sshd_config file to set up per-user configuration directives.

Comment: But that controls access based on username and host without regard to what authentication method they're using.  He wants to control which authentication methods are allowed depending on the host.

Comment: I was suggesting that one might be able to add PasswordAuthentication directives under the MatchUser user-specific settings. Haven't tried it, do you know if that would work? I've thus far only used Chroot and force-command settings under MatchUser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make this work by configuring sshd with PAM and Pubkey auth, and then configure PAM to only allow access from certain subnets.  This trickery works because sshd doesn't ask PAM anything about key based auth.

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config (I think these are the defaults anyways on Ubuntu) something like:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
```

In /etc/pam.d/sshd uncomment the pam_access line (I believe on Ubuntu it's present in the right sequence but commented out):

```
account required pam_access.so
```

In /etc/security/access.conf:

```
+:ALL:192.168.1.0/24
```

Note: I have not tested this at all.